# Self referencing entity in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need a tree structure in my Doctrine ORM entity.
My requirements are to have a reference to the parent and root entity.
Also the root entity should have a reference to itself. That makes problems.
My Entity has amongst other things these fields:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
 */
private UuidInterface $id;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Example")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private self $root;
```

Then I fill the root reference just before persist and flush.

```
$example->setRoot($example);

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->persist($example);
$entityManager->flush();
```

But this leads to the following PostgreSQL error, because the root entity is not referenced well:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO example (id, parent_id, root_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["d1ed4480-e872-4c13-bbd8-7597d465a3cd", null, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "root_id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (d1ed4480-e872-4c13-bbd8-7597d465a3cd, null, null).

It would be easy to save the entity first and modify it after that. But since I have already the generated primary key, this detour should not be needed.